# Creating file in existing directory on external sd card for android application

Tags: java, android, file, sd-card

my goal is to write some text in a non-existing file in a given directory on the external sd card. Unfortunately I am not able to create such a file in the directory with my android application. 
I found several code examples which worked for others, but they do not work for my application. Thus any suggestions are more than appreciated. Thank you!

Here is my relevant code: 
1. Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

2. Java-Class

```
FileOutputStream fos ;
if( Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState()) ) {
   try {
      File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
      File file = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator +
                           "givenDirectory" + File.separator + "newFile");
      fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
      String data = "some text";
      fos.write(data.getBytes());
      fos.close();
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

I am using Android-version 5.1.1 on my mobile phone. The extract of the java class is part of a static void which only contains the quoted code.

Problem: file is not created

Comment: "my goal is to write some text in a non-existing file in a given directory on the external sd card" -- your code is for working with [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html). This is not [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) (how I would interpret "external sd card"). Beyond that, you should look at LogCat for any Java stack traces associated with your exception handlers, and you should use `adb shell` for seeing if the file exists, since you're not indexing it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need Android Runtime Permissions: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html